# Inconsistent results for iframe with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, iframe, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the twitter username of crypto currencies from coinmarketcap (https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/social/). Some of them don't have the twitter iframe like (https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/social/).

The problem is that the iframe loads in around 3 seconds. But I tested my program many times and I found that the iframe does not always load even after I wait for 5 seconds. Sometimes I manually tried to open the page and it didn't even appear on the screen (but very rare).

I am expecting that it should work perfectly and scrape everything, but it seems that it is prone to error as it depends on loading time and server response?

Is there a better more stable way of doing this? This is my first web scraping project and it seems like the only solution that could work

Is there another method which I could use while waiting?

I know that you can get the source from the iframe and scrape it but I was not able to find it.

Here is my function:

```
def get_crypto_currency_social(slug):


url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/"+slug+"/social/"
browser = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
# .add_argument('headless')
browser.get(url) 
try:
    wait(browser, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "twitter-widget-0")))
except:
    pass

html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

market_cap = soup.find('div', {'class': 'statsValue___2iaoZ'}).text.split('$')[-1]
coin_name  = soup.find('small', {'class': 'nameSymbol___1arQV'}).text
coin_rank  = soup.find('div', {'class': 'namePillPrimary___2-GWA'}).text.split('#')[-1]

try:
    iframe = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0]
    browser.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    twitter_username = browser.find_element_by_class_name("customisable-highlight").text
except NoSuchElementException:
    twitter_username = ""
except: 
    print("Error getting twitter username")
finally:
    browser.quit()

return {
    "coin_rank": coin_rank,
    "market_cap": market_cap,
    "coin_name": coin_name,
    "twitter_username": twitter_username
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a random delay b/w times you could probably make use of WebDriverWait class from selenium.

**Sample code :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"YOUR IFRAME XPATH")))
```

Comment: I tried this but I am still getting different results each time. I even have it to wait for 15-20 seconds and I still get nothing back from the iframe, it simply does not load. Sometimes I get it in 2 seconds, sometimes I dont'. I changed the code a little and get the twitter data in one try/except when I use WebDriverWait as I am entering the iframe directly. I don't know if I should get used to getting inconsistent results or there is a way to do this.

Comment: @Filip : try `driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds` after browser initialization

Comment: ok, so I tried this way and it still misses some. 
I also tried using scroll hoping that the iframe would be triggered somehow...
I turned off headless browser off and there was one page where the iframe loaded but it didn't scrape the text. So it's probably my code? Maybe the class changes dynamically when I get the twitter username?

Comment: @Filip : Let me poke around this one after some time.